# How to migrate a project from a CVS repository on one AIX Server to an SVN repository on another AIX server?

Tags: svn, migration, cvs

I have a CVS repository on one AIX server and it has 3 projects in the repository
I have another AIX server on which I have SVN hosted. I have more than 10 projects on SVN.

I need the 3 projects on CVS to come to SVN.

Could anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with this, but the [SVN Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.forcvs.convert.html) describes the difficulties in this migration:

> This is an extremely difficult problem to solve; it involves deducing changesets in the absence of atomicity and translating between the systems' completely orthogonal branching policies, among other complications. Still, a handful of tools claim to at least partially support the ability to convert existing CVS repositories into Subversion ones.

It then recommends a Python-based tool called *cvs2svn* to perform the migration:

> The most popular (and mature) conversion tool is cvs2svn (http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/), a Python program originally created by members of Subversion's own development community. This tool is meant to run exactly once: it scans your CVS repository multiple times and attempts to deduce commits, branches, and tags as best it can. When it finishes, the result is either a Subversion repository or a portable Subversion dump file representing your code's history. See the web site for detailed instructions and caveats.

Your easiest option is to just import the most recent version of your CVS projects into SVN.  You won't have any history, but you could keep a read-only version of the CVS repository around for that.